# Dynamic Database Connections in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database

As already known we can add more database connection in `Laravel` by updating `app/config/database.php` file in the `connections` array and using `Schema::connection('mysql2')->...` amd `= DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);` to do queries.

BUT, what if I want 50 databases or more, I can create a table databases in the main database that has all the data needed to connect to every database on my app, but all I need in to send `DB::connection()` or `Schema::connection()` a direct array or something similar to that!

How can we exactly do this in Laravel 10?

Comment: Maybe this will helpful https://tenancyforlaravel.com/